# Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)-NodeJs/MySQL

Tags: mysql, node.js

1. I opened "Xampp"
2. then I clicked Start for "Apache" in the Xampp
3. then I clicked Start for "MySQL"  in the Xampp
4. then I clicked Admin, After pressing "Admin" on the Xampp, a page "MyPhpAdmin" appeared in the browser
5. then I am implementing this instruction "npm start" in VS Code for NodeJs Project

but I get this Error :

```
  ✖ Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)
  [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

what can I should do?

Comment: In your node.js code it looks like the mysql user is missing. It should be `'root'@'localhost'` i think.

Comment: @Roland Starke How can I do what you say ? , what can i do in NodeJs ?, How can i be sure that the mysql user is missing ?

Comment: Depends on the code. Is is a public project? Then i could take a look. Else i would search for a config or readme.

Comment: @Roland Starke No ,it is not public

Comment: Can you share the code? Idk. i am still in the dark. Else like you could try connecting to the database with this lib: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql and test if it works. (user 'root', host: 'localhost', password: '')

Comment: @Roland Starke  Thank you , my Problem was solved , I forget to put ".env" file for database